# iframe not adding to height of div

Tags: css, iframe

On a page where I have an `iframe` linked to a youtube video:

```
<div class="header">
    stuff
</div>

<div class="container">
    <iframe class="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    stuff
</div>
```

The outcome however is that the footer is displayed over the bottom half of the youtube link image as the page does not seem to recognise the actual size of the `iframe`.

Is there is a reason and solution to this?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php hope this helps

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. Really useful tip.

Comment: you are welcome :)